# Add Play/Pause button to bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have read almost all the threads regarding to the bootstrap carousel, but haven't found an answer to my question.
I have added two control buttons (play/pause) to the carousel, but each button fires the function from the default/first slide. I would like to be able to pause the current slide and play from the current slide whenever the click event happens.

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="/_catalogs/masterpage/UHN/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.carousel').carousel({ interval:6000 });  

        $('#playButton').click(function () {
            $('#homeCarousel').carousel('cycle');
        });
        $('#pauseButton').click(function () {
            $('#homeCarousel').carousel('pause');
        });
    });

</script>
```

And the two controls:

```html
<!--Carousel controls -->
<button id="playButton">Play</button>
<button id="pauseButton">Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should be working.  I'd make sure that your click events are firing as you expect them to because some elements of the bootstrap carousel can appear above your elements and prevent clicks.

If you add the following controls in **HTML**:

```html
<div id="carouselButtons">
    <button id="playButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
     </button>
    <button id="pauseButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Then the following **JavaScript** should control starting and stopping on any frame:

```js
$('#playButton').click(function () {
    $('#homeCarousel').carousel('cycle');
});
$('#pauseButton').click(function () {
    $('#homeCarousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

As related to my first point, to get them to appear properly within the carousel, you can style the button group with the following **CSS**:

```css
#carouselButtons {
    margin-left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

## [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XFcSv/)

For this functionality to make the most sense, you probably want the carousel to continue moving, even when hovering over it (otherwise after the play selection is made, the cycling behavior won't start up again until you move the mouse).

According to the [carousel docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel):

> **Option** - pause
>   **Default** - "hover" - Pauses the cycling of the carousel on mouseenter and resumes the cycling of the carousel on mouseleave.

Instead, make sure you turn this off when you initialize the carousel like this:

```js
$('#homeCarousel').carousel({
    interval:2000,
    pause: "false"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful modifications to the code, I am afraid it only works on the first click, the second click and beyond,  doesn't fire the event. Also, I've realized it's not working on IE10 (even the jsFiddle example); could it be a general bug? Thanks again KyleMit!

Comment: What part is not working?  The fiddle works fine for me on IE,FF, and Chrome.  Remember for the [bootstrap carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel), the default `pause` option is `"hover"`, meaning the carousel will always pause when hovering.  Try moving your cursor away for the play to begin working again.  Alternately, try this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XFcSv/1/) with the `pause: "false"` option set

Comment: By setting pause to false it's resolved and now it's also working in IE. Thanks so much KyleMit

Answer (score 1):

This was my approach. You can style the .pause and .play class however you see fit, but I'm just using plain text for demo purposes:

```
$('.carousel-control.pause').click(function() {
        var controls = $(this);
        if (controls.hasClass('pause')) {
            controls.text('Resume').removeClass('pause').toggleClass('play');
            $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
        } else {
            controls.text('Pause').removeClass('play').toggleClass('pause');
            $('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
        }
    });
```

Here is your detonator

```
<a class="carousel-control pause" href="javascript:void(0);">Pause</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who would like the play/pause buttons to switch off.
[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/thetaPC/z23Laqcp/)

**Javascript:**

```
 $("button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("id") === "pauseButton") {
    $('#homeCarousel').carousel('pause');
    $(this).attr("id", "playButton");
    $("span", this).toggleClass("glyphicon-play glyphicon-pause");
  } else {
    $('#homeCarousel').carousel('cycle');
    $(this).attr("id", "pauseButton");
    $("span", this).toggleClass("glyphicon-pause glyphicon-play");
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="carouselButtons">
    <button id="pauseButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: The pause button in the fiddle link provided does not pause the carousel.  But I do appreciate the display of a single button at a time.  I independently sought the same feature and accomplished it by modifying KyleMit's fiddle to default the Play button as `display:none;` and apply `$('#playButton,#pauseButton').toggle();` to both button functions ...plus some other modifications