# Start bootstrap carousel stopped on page load with interval false

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to make bootstrap carousel stopped and make a call to play it when you want?

Bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs and older answers:

```
.carousel('cycle')
```

and

```
.carousel('pause')
```

should do the job or am I wrong? See also [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20616834/2379196). Even if it isn't specific for BS4 the operations are still there and should do the same thing according to the docs I checked and you linked.

I'm not seeing a way to pause it completely on initialization but maybe I overlooked something. But you can simply call `.carousel('pause')` directly after init which should fit your requirement.

Comment: ('pause') This is for pausing on :hover, not for stopping it.

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga That is not true, read the docs "Stops the carousel from cycling through items.", also check the old answer I posted. The initialization parameter "pause" seems to be different from .carousel('pause') that is also what the linked answer suggests. The fiddle included in the original answer demonstrates that, if you had followed my suggestion.

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga So please try that before saying it won't work as it does for BS3. I assume there would be no big difference in BS4. I tried the fiddle myself and it exactly does what you are asking for with the solution I proposed you.

Comment: Well, so maybe I can't get to make this work myself, sorry. Can I provide the JS code where I want to stop/start to insert these strings that you provided? Thanks.

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga Did this http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XFcSv/ not work for you? This is an example on how to do it on BS3. This is also included in the post I referenced above! This starts and stops the carousel with a button. The only difference is would make to the code is to call carousel('pause') after initialization to prevent auto cycle.

Comment: I don't want to use a button, I want to make it start when intersection observer apply the class for showing it (the slider is hide by default, so when is hide I want to make it stop, and when the user reach the intersection point and the slider shows, I want the slider to start.  You can see it in my page (middle aprox) https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga You probably already found out that the button trigger event is just an example. As with every manual action you can control it depending on whatever event you'd like ;).Also with intersection observer which is supposed to call.carousel('cycle') when the current viewport contains the carousel or whatever..